# How to use variable in Azure CLI script within Devops release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to pass the below variable to a inline script in the Azure CLI Job in Azure release Pipelines, to get the principal ID of an identity:

```
miid=$(az identity show -g Resourcegroup -n prodaks-agentpool --query "principalId" -o tsv)
```

I am then running the below commands to set a policy in keyvault for the identity.

```
call az keyvault set-policy -n proddigitalkeyvault1 --key-permissions get --object-id $miid
call az keyvault set-policy -n proddigitalkeyvault1 --secret-permission get --object-id $miid
call az keyvault set-policy -n proddigitalkeyvault1 --certificate-permissions get --object-id $miid
```

I receive the error: "miid is not recognized as an internal command". Is it possible to add this variable into the inline script? This script works fine when running from my own machine.

Comment: What scripting environment are you using? Bash, Windows command line, PowerShell? Your first line and the way you reference the `$miid` variable looks like Bash syntax, but the error message you're showing is a Windows shell error message. Make sure you're running your script using the correct OS and interpreter.

Comment: Pretty sure Azure DevOps should not be part of the question. This is purely az cli right?

Comment: I am running a inline Batch script in Azure Devops using the above commands.
To add variables the miid variable to this script, is it best to add it to the inline script or environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my type of script to shell and removed the "call" command. This script now runs ok in Azure Devops

Comment: @Callun Hester Nice move